# Is it possible to put http torrent tracker under CDN to prevent DDOS?

Tags: cdn, cloudflare, bittorrent

I am thinking about setting up torrent tracker on the same dedicated server where torrent related website will be located. I want to do that because my website and tracker will interact with each other and I want theese interactions to be smooth and don't want to mess with replication.

I will use cloudflare or other CDN to prevent DDOS attacks on my website. But I also want to secure my http torrent tracker (XBT tracker) running on different port. So I also want torrents to go through CDN like through proxy but without caching and captcha, because torrent software can't solve captcha. Is it possible to proxy http torrent-tracker via CDN like cloudflare or I have to order additional DDOSable server just for torrent-tracker?

Comment: It is possible to do, but that doesn't guarantee that it will work with every CDN and every torrent tracker. Whether it will work with your specific combination is unknown to me. One major caveat is that a tracker is expected to know the IP of each client. Once you put any kind of proxy in front of it, the client IPs can no longer be seen by the tracker in the same way it would usually do.

Comment: @kasperd This is actually not true - most proxies will include the original IP as payload into the header. Whether the software is compatible is another thing totally.

Comment: @TomTom It cannot find the client IP in the **same way** it would usually do. It can find the client IP in a **different** way, if the tracker was implemented with support for that.

Comment: Not same way is not "unavailable". Simple like that.

Comment: Thanks guys, if ip is the only problem I have an workaround: I can put nginx-proxy between tracker and CDN and convert CDN's additional header with ip to actual header with ip. Or maybe I can just edit torrent-tracker source, so it uses another header. But won't CDN break the client->tracker connection by asking captcha or some other way? Because torrent tracker connections may seem like DDOS attacks to CDN. I wonder if captcha can be disabled on CDNs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think you will gain *anything* by using CloudFlare or any other CDN for the Torrent Tracker.

The whole point of a CDN is to offload the work to it by **caching** the replies to requests.

With a torrent tracker each request is pretty much unique to each client.
So they cannot be cached (or it wouldn't make any difference if they where), making a CDN essentially useless for that specific type of workload.

Take for example TL. It's a huge private torrent tracker. Its website is on CloudFlare, but its tracker is on a server in Luxemburg. No CDN seems to be involved. There could be a cluster behind that IP to be able to handle all the requests, but my guess is, not a CDN.

Each request a client makes will be unique each time they make it.

> An example of this GET message could be:
>
> ```
> http://some.tracker.com:999/announce
> ?info_hash=12345678901234567890
> &peer_id=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
> &ip=255.255.255.255
> &port=6881
> &downloaded=1234
> &left=98765
> &event=stopped
> ```

https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrent_Tracker_Protocol

More details: http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html

Even if every parameter is the same for all clients (which isn't - peerid is unique per client, per torrent according to the BEP0003) you would still have unique stuff in there **per request per client**.
Eg:

```
&downloaded=1234
&left=98765
```

The above parameters change with each subsequent request of the torrent client depending on how much traffic has it done since the last request.

CDNs will usually cache content based on the request URI. So if the request is unique everytime, it won't be able to serve any cached content thus defeating their purpose.

Now that I think of it, if your tracker is anonymous you *could, maybe*, use a very custom configuration on a Varnish to be able to cache the replies for each info_hash, ignoring the requests' uniqueness. But this way your tracker will not be able to measure any real statistics (total up/down/peers/whatever) since only a small percentage of requests will reach the tracker.

And this way you will not be really protected for any DDoS (even though Varnish is an awesome piece of software that can handle an amazing amounts of requests!)

Update:

There are a few providers that have DDoS protection hardware (eg: Arbor Peakflow). Those could allow you to run your tracker without any CDN or caching and be able to block the DDoS attacks from reaching to your server. But of-course solutions like this have their own cost attached :)

Comment: It will hide my torrent-tracker ip. And as I want it to be on the same server (or replication would slow down changes from website), I have to hide tracker ip to prevent DDOS (and hide server location of course for security). Most CDNs offer "hide server ip" feature, otherwise DDOS protection would be useless. My question is about: Can CDN with turned off caching broke http torrent-tracker protocol?

Comment: I am not very familiar with CloudFlare specifically, but I believe the point of those CDNs is that by caching the content, the clients' requests do not hit the backend server and since the CDN has much more bandwidth it can absorb the DDoS attack. So without caching, will it actually prevent the DDoS? I don't know. Regarding your question, if your torrent tracker supports the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header then it should be fine. Be careful though, if your tracker makes outgoing connections (to check client connectable status for example) then a CDN won't hide the tracker's IP apparently.

Comment: thanks, that is what I needed to know. I will check if my tracker makes outgoing connections.

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost 5 years late, but this is more for people googling. I actually have my tracker behind Cloudflare because it helps with routing traffic for users with IPv6. It helps make sure they're routed to use IPv4 for the tracker. And it allows more people to use the tracker. If I wanted to I could add the DDOS protection as well but I use Page rules to bypass caching and a lot of other options.

Your page rules should look like this:

```
http://tracker.example.com:8080/*
Cache Level: Bypass
```

and

```
http://tracker.example.com:2052/*
Cache Level: Bypass
```

First you have to look up Cloudflares supported ports, use one that works for you. There's a list here:

By default, Cloudflare proxies traffic destined for the HTTP/HTTPS ports listed below.

HTTP ports supported by Cloudflare:

```
80
8080
8880
2052
2082
2086
2095
```

HTTPS ports supported by Cloudflare:

```
443
2053
2083
2087
2096
8443
```

Then you need to put Nginx in front of your torrent tracker. For example if you use Xbt Tracker you need to use Nginx rewrite like this, in "default.conf" or whatever you'd like to name it .conf in the conf.d folder:

```
server {

listen       8080;

server_name  localhost;
  location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?ip=$remote_addr break; 
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2052/;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host                  $http_host;
proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
access_log off;
log_not_found off;
  }
}
```

Basically you would be running your tracker from port 2052 for example and then run Nginx proxied from port 8080. And then you would insert port 8080 in your torrents.

I think that's about it, you can look up how to add more options to Nginx like the amount of workers and keep alive time.

If you don't put Nginx in front of your tracker then the tracker will get all Cloudflare ip addresses and won't be able to communicate and track properly.

Also make another file in the Nginx conf.d folder called cloudflare.conf and put the following inside, this will allow you to get the real ips:

```
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 131.0.72.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 172.64.0.0/13;
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;

set_real_ip_from 2400:cb00::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:8100::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2405:b500::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2606:4700::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2803:f800::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2c0f:f248::/32;
set_real_ip_from 2a06:98c0::/29;

real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
```

Enjoy. And monitor your database for the correct Ips to make sure it's working well.