# Is it possible to put http torrent tracker (XBT) behind cloudflare tunnel

Tags: cloudflare, bittorrent, torrent

Similar question in this thread
[Is it possible to put http torrent tracker under CDN to prevent DDOS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/708435/is-it-possible-to-put-http-torrent-tracker-under-cdn-to-prevent-ddos)

basically xbt works on port 7210 (by default) and if I do redirect with tunnel, I lose IP address of the peer because xbt doesn't know how to handle "CF-Connecting-IP"

If I put Nginx in front of xbt (per solution from other thread) I get "too many redirects" error